# MongoDB locks on insert operations

Tags: mongodb, insert, locking

While new rows are being inserted into a MongoDB collection, is it still possible to query old records ?

Is there any difference between WiredTiger and MMAPv1 in that regard ?

Comment: There is a manual section ["FAQ: Concurrency"](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/faq/concurrency/) that already explains everything

Answer (score 4, accepted):

WiredTiger

[WiredTiger](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/wiredtiger/) uses document level locking. WiredTiger is the default storage engine for mongodb from release 3.0

MMAPv1

[MMAPv1](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/mmapv1/) uses collection level locking from release 3.0 which is a huge improvement, as earlier,  it was using database level locking. Also MMAPv1 was the default storage engine for mongodb prior to release 3.0.

***Answer to your question now***

As WiredTiger provides document level locking, and WiredTiger is the default storage engine from 3.0, you would be able to query old records in collection in Mongodb 3.0 and higher. But since Mongodb was using MMAPv1 as default storage engine before release 3.0, so in earlier releases, you would not be able to search for old records in a collection.

For more information, please refer to the following link :-
https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/faq/concurrency/